# ¿Función que recorra la propiedad nombre de los textbox y valide con base al valor de un combobox?

Tags: textbox

Esto creando un formulario para obtener costo de venta, donde una de las primeras cosas es elegir de un combobox un número del uno al quince.

Por ejemplo, si elijo el 1, de los quince textbox sólo debe quedar habilitado el primero, si elijo el número 2 en el combobox, deben quedar habilitados solo el primero y el segundo textbox y así.

El tema es que quiero crear una función que compare el nombre del textbox (name en la propiedades), extraiga el segundo caracter del nombre, que es un número y lo compare con el valor elegido en el combobox, para desabilite todos los demás casillero que van después del número elegido.

ejemplo los textbox se llaman i1, i2, i3..... i15
en el combobox puedo elegir valores del 1 al 15... Si elijo el valor 1, los textbox del 2 al 15 se inhabiltan, si elijo 5, los textbox del 6 al 15 se deshabilitan.

por eso los textbox tienen nombre en secuencia, pero no sé cómo extraer del textbox llamado i1, sólo el valor 1 y compararlo con el valor seleccionado en el combobox.

Si alguien me puede ayudar. Mil gracias.

Comment: Sin código a modo de un [mcve] dificilmente alguien podrá ayudarte. Te recomiendo leer [ask] y también a realizar el [tour], de paso te ganas tu primera medalla. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta en cuaquier momento.

Comment: Hola Ambar, bienvenida, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.